# Call recording using audiosource MIC always fails

Tags: android, voice-recording

I am coding a call recording feature using MIC as audio source, as VOICE_CALL is not allowed in some devices.
Below is my code.

But sometimes this code crashes with Null pointer exception and sometimes does not stop the `media-recorder` I mean recording goes on after the call also.

Broadcast receiver registered as `phone-state` listener....

Any help would be appreciated. You can find my code below.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Calendar;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class TestingCallmonitor extends BroadcastReceiver{
 private MediaRecorder mediaRecorder=null;
 boolean flag=false;  
    @Override
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
         String action = intent.getAction();

         if(action.equalsIgnoreCase("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"))
          {
           if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) 
              {

               //Toast.makeText(context, "ringing", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 

              }         

           if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) 
              {
                 if(flag) {   
                           mediaRecorder.stop();
                           mediaRecorder.release();
                           mediaRecorder=null;
                           }
                flag=false;
              }     

           if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) 
            {  
               flag=true;
               Calendar c=Calendar.getInstance();
               int hour=c.get(Calendar.HOUR);
               int min=c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
               int sec=c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
               //Toast.makeText(context, "started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Callrecord");
                if (!folder.exists()) {
                    folder.mkdir();
                }
                String mFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
                mFileName += "/Callrecord/call"+hour+"-"+min+"-"+sec+".3gp";
                mediaRecorder=new MediaRecorder();
                mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
                mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
                mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
                //mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.getAudioSourceMax());
                mediaRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(44100);
                mediaRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(16);
                mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(mFileName);
                try{mediaRecorder.prepare();}catch(IOException e){Toast.makeText(context, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
                mediaRecorder.start();

             }    

         }   

    }
```

}

Comment: _"sometimes this code crashes"_ Where exactly does it crash? What does the exception trace look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here i added the call recorder sample source code for. Please try and let me know.

**RecordService.java**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.Exception;
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.app.Service;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.util.Log;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class RecordService 
    extends Service
    implements MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener, MediaRecorder.OnErrorListener
{
    private static final String TAG = "CallRecorder";

    public static final String DEFAULT_STORAGE_LOCATION = "/sdcard/callrecorder";
    private static final int RECORDING_NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    private MediaRecorder recorder = null;
    private boolean isRecording = false;
    private File recording = null;;
    private final int audioformat = 3;


    private File makeOutputFile (SharedPreferences prefs)
    {
    File dir = new File(DEFAULT_STORAGE_LOCATION);

    // test dir for existence and writeability
    if (!dir.exists()) {
        try {
            dir.mkdirs();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("CallRecorder", "RecordService::makeOutputFile unable to create directory " + dir + ": " + e);
            Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "CallRecorder was unable to create the directory " + dir + " to store recordings: " + e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            t.show();
            return null;
        }
    } else {
        if (!dir.canWrite()) {
            Log.e(TAG, "RecordService::makeOutputFile does not have write permission for directory: " + dir);
            Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "CallRecorder does not have write permission for the directory directory " + dir + " to store recordings", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            t.show();
            return null;
        }
    }

    // test size

    // create filename based on call data
    String prefix = "call";
    //SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd_HH:MM:SS");
    //prefix = sdf.format(new Date()) + "-callrecording";

    // add info to file name about what audio channel we were recording
    prefix += "-channel" + 1 + "-";

    // create suffix based on format
    String suffix = "";
    switch (audioformat) {
    case MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP:
        suffix = ".3gpp";
        break;
    case MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4:
        suffix = ".mpg";
        break;
    case MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.RAW_AMR:
        suffix = ".amr";
        break;
    }

    try {
        return File.createTempFile(prefix, suffix, dir);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("CallRecorder", "RecordService::makeOutputFile unable to create temp file in " + dir + ": " + e);
        Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "CallRecorder was unable to create temp file in " + dir + ": " + e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        t.show();
        return null;
    }
    }

    public void onCreate()
    {
    super.onCreate();
    recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    Log.i("CallRecorder", "onCreate created MediaRecorder object");
    }

    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    Log.i("CallRecorder", "RecordService::onStartCommand called while isRecording:" + isRecording);

    if (isRecording) return;

    Context c = getApplicationContext();
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(c);

    Boolean shouldRecord = prefs.getBoolean(Preferences.PREF_RECORD_CALLS, false);
    if (!shouldRecord) {
        Log.i("CallRecord", "RecordService::onStartCommand with PREF_RECORD_CALLS false, not recording");
        //return START_STICKY;
        return;
    }
    recording = makeOutputFile(prefs);
    if (recording == null) {
        recorder = null;
        return; //return 0;
    }

       try {
        // These calls will throw exceptions unless you set the 
        // android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO permission for your app
        recorder.reset();
        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        recorder.setOutputFormat(audioformat);
        Log.d("CallRecorder", "set output " + audioformat);
        recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);
        Log.d("CallRecorder", "set encoder default");
        recorder.setOutputFile(recording.getAbsolutePath());
        Log.d("CallRecorder", "set file: " + recording);
        //recorder.setMaxDuration(msDuration); //1000); // 1 seconds
        //recorder.setMaxFileSize(bytesMax); //1024*1024); // 1KB

        recorder.setOnInfoListener(this);
        recorder.setOnErrorListener(this);

        try {
            recorder.prepare();
        } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
            Log.e("CallRecorder", "RecordService::onStart() IOException attempting recorder.prepare()\n");
            Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "CallRecorder was unable to start recording: " + e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            t.show();
            recorder = null;
            return; //return 0; //START_STICKY;
        }
        Log.d("CallRecorder", "recorder.prepare() returned");

        recorder.start();
        isRecording = true;
        Log.i("CallRecorder", "recorder.start() returned");
        updateNotification(true);
    } catch (java.lang.Exception e) {
        Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "CallRecorder was unable to start recording: " + e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        t.show();

        Log.e("CallRecorder", "RecordService::onStart caught unexpected exception", e);
        recorder = null;
    }

    return; //return 0; //return START_STICKY;
    }

    public void onDestroy()
    {
    super.onDestroy();

    if (null != recorder) {
        Log.i("CallRecorder", "RecordService::onDestroy calling recorder.release()");
        isRecording = false;
        recorder.release();
        Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "CallRecorder finished recording call to " + recording, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        t.show();
    }

    updateNotification(false);
    }


    // methods to handle binding the service

    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
    {
    return null;
    }

    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent)
    {
    return false;
    }

    public void onRebind(Intent intent)
    {
    }


    private void updateNotification(Boolean status)
    {
    Context c = getApplicationContext();
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(c);

    String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);

    if (status) {
        int icon = R.drawable.rec;
        CharSequence tickerText = "Recording call from channel " + prefs.getString(Preferences.PREF_AUDIO_SOURCE, "1");
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);

        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence contentTitle = "CallRecorder Status";
        CharSequence contentText = "Recording call from channel...";
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, RecordService.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(RECORDING_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
    } else {
        mNotificationManager.cancel(RECORDING_NOTIFICATION_ID);
    }
    }

    // MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener
    public void onInfo(MediaRecorder mr, int what, int extra)
    {
    Log.i("CallRecorder", "RecordService got MediaRecorder onInfo callback with what: " + what + " extra: " + extra);
    isRecording = false;
    }

    // MediaRecorder.OnErrorListener
    public void onError(MediaRecorder mr, int what, int extra) 
    {
    Log.e("CallRecorder", "RecordService got MediaRecorder onError callback with what: " + what + " extra: " + extra);
    isRecording = false;
    mr.release();
    }
}
```

**PhoneListener.java**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.util.Log;

public class PhoneListener extends PhoneStateListener
{
    private Context context;

    public PhoneListener(Context c) {
    Log.i("CallRecorder", "PhoneListener constructor");
    context = c;
    }

    public void onCallStateChanged (int state, String incomingNumber)
    {
    Log.d("CallRecorder", "PhoneListener::onCallStateChanged state:" + state + " incomingNumber:" + incomingNumber);

    switch (state) {
    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
        Log.d("CallRecorder", "CALL_STATE_IDLE, stoping recording");
        Boolean stopped = context.stopService(new Intent(context, RecordService.class));
        Log.i("CallRecorder", "stopService for RecordService returned " + stopped);
        break;
    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
        Log.d("CallRecorder", "CALL_STATE_RINGING");
        break;
    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
        Log.d("CallRecorder", "CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK starting recording");
        Intent callIntent = new Intent(context, RecordService.class);
        ComponentName name = context.startService(callIntent);
        if (null == name) {
            Log.e("CallRecorder", "startService for RecordService returned null ComponentName");
        } else {
            Log.i("CallRecorder", "startService returned " + name.flattenToString());
        }
        break;
    }
    }
}
```

Hope it should helpful for you.Its working fine for me. Please try and let me know.
For more info please download the sample code form

[Call Recorder](https://github.com/esnyder/callrecorder)

Comment: Praveen the app record the voice when you have incoming call or outgoing call that time only the call should be record the voice and it will store the voice in sd card.

Comment: The type RecordService must implement the inherited abstract method MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener.onInfo(MediaRecorder, 
  int, int)   getting this error

Comment: Hi Praveen i modified the RecordService.java class please try with latest one. Please try and let me know. Thanks for your info.

Comment: Not working..  How to register  PhoneListener in manifest file. Its not broadcast recevier then how does that get notification of incoming call

Comment: Praveen i am using the code from the github . Please download the sample project and run in your environment and use in your application https://github.com/esnyder/callrecorder. Thanks

Comment: Thank you so much.. It works wonderfully..  and You forgot to tell about "CallBroadcastReceiver"  broadcast receiver in the answer. this reeiver makes everything possible there.

Comment: It worked for me also. Thank you.. putting this as right answer

Comment: @Jeba  In preference when i set audio source to VOICE_CALL app throws an exception and does not record the call.  When I set it to VOICE_UPLINK  it records the call but recorded voice is stretched.

Comment: Avjit, can u share ur input on this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45391545/issue-with-mediarecorder-for-opponent-sound